# Google openID login integration

Tags: android, android-studio, google-openid

I followed [google oauth tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/oauth-practices/mobile-apps-for-complex-login-systems/samplecode) to implement openId login for my app.

I have used `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`, but some how webview not showing Google login page in emulator. Just blank page showing up.

Here is my relevant code snippet. Any inputs?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud"));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

`WebViewActivity` code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Allow the title bar to show loading progress.
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);

        // Load the page
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.getData() != null) {
            webview.loadUrl(intent.getDataString());
        }
................
}
```

My web app using `OpenId`, so `OAuth` is not an option for me.

Comment: In your `Uri.parse` you have `ud` instead of `id`. Is that a problem?

Comment: @Houseman: I tried both, both didn't work. I think there is one more step missing (discovery) to get end point (server url). But I couldn't find any example which is doing discovery.

Comment: For the record, Google [no longer supports OpenID 2.0 and suggests migrating to OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenID2Migration).

Answer (score 1):

I do the same what mentioned in the sample.

When I tried opening the url you mentioned `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`

I am getting the following screen .

[image]

When I tried the url `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud` it redirects to `https://accounts.google.com/o/openid2/auth`

and giving the following screen in my webview

[image]

I think that url supposed to have these parameters along with it

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
 client_id=424911365001.apps.googleusercontent.com&
 response_type=code&
 scope=openid%20email&
 redirect_uri=https://oa2cb.example.com/&
 state=security_token%3D138r5719ru3e1%26url%3Dhttps://oa2cb.example.com/myHome&
 login_hint=jsmith@example.com&
 openid.realm=example.com&
 hd=example.com

as mentioned here `https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#sendauthrequest`

The screen takes some time to appear so please wait for a while to see the outputs which I have posted. Make sure you are not connected to any restricted wifi network while trying. Better to try with any 2g or 3g network.

**Updated**

Check this once for Open Id

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#settingup (Check 3rd point for request)

About the end point

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#endpoint

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I think client_id is not static and we need to discover it. How did you get that URL? Before sending authrequest we need to discovery (AFAIK), isn't it?

Comment: Which URL you are talking about ? the one  `https://accounts.google.com/o/openid2/auth` automatically redirect when i tried to load `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud` in webview. Client Id I think you can get from Google API console by registering you app.

Comment: Yes I am talking about clientid, Do we need to register app? Let me check that tonight. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, AFAIK you have to register your App in order to use Google OpenId using your app packageneme and Certificate SHA1 Signature in Google API Console.

Comment: No success so far. It seems the approach you suggested (Registering app) is oAuth. I am still struggling.

Comment: Exactly I followed those documents before posting this question, if you observe your second screenshot, that would be the results when I use end point URL (but based on documentation it should discover URL). That is point I am struggling to find answer. If I can successfully discover I think issue would be resolved.

Comment: @PiyushAgarwal I am facing this error ```DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: 'No OpenID endpoint found``` I am using this ```https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id``` can you help me more